# Can't select Jquery elements after reloading a div with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a message inbox which I refresh with `AJAX` after removing a message, resulting in a new message inbox without the message.

```
<div class="container>
    <div class="message_box">
        <div class="title"> </div>
        <div class="message"> </div>
        <div class="title"> </div>
        <div class="message"> </div>
        <div class="title"> </div>
        <div class="message"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My HTML code looks like that, when the document is ready, I call a show/hide message function:

```
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            message_show();
        });

        function message_show()
        {
            $("div.message").hide();                
            $(document).on("click", "div.title", function()
            {
                $("#" + this.id + ".message").fadeToggle("fast");
                $("#fold" + this.id).fadeToggle("fast");
            });             
        }
```

This works fine, when the page loads, the messages are hidden, and the moment you click on a title the messages show up, and the fold icon changes.

However, the moment I refresh the content with AJAX by using a `.get()` to remove the message:

```
function delete_message(message_id) 
{
    $.get("message_inbox.php",{delete_id:message_id}, function(data)
    {
        $("div#messages_inbox").load("message_inbox.php div#messages_inbox > *");
        // $("div.message").hide();
        message_show();
    });
}
```

After using the `.load` the message divs aren't hidden anymore.

I managed to select the div.title by using the `$(document).on` to toggle them, which works, but hiding the messages, when the content has been loaded doesn't seem to work.

Neither was I able to hide the div inside the `$.get` (the part I left commented)

Comment: Please look into re binding events following an ajax call. What is happening is every time you use AJAX on DOM elements the events are wiped out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("div#messages_inbox").load(...)` - You're overwriting everything that is inside of `#messages_inbox` when `.load` completes.

If what is inside of `div#messages_inbox > *` in the returned content from `message_inbox.php` does not contain `div.message` or `div.title`, it will look like `message_show()` does nothing.

See documentation for [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

You'll also want to make your call to `message_show()` as `.load`'s callback function to ensure the content has been loaded prior to using it:

```
function delete_message(message_id) 
{
    $.get("message_inbox.php",{delete_id:message_id}, function(data)
    {
        $("div#messages_inbox").load("message_inbox.php div#messages_inbox > *", message_show);
    });
}
```